# Could NATO survive destruction of power stations?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history, cold-war

I'm writing about an alternate history where alien ship lands on a moon in the beginning of the 70's. One of the Apollo missions is send over there to establish contact. The aliens don't take too kindly on NASA's effort and as a punishment they obliterate all the power stations in the western world (North America, Western Europe) and leave.

Could NATO countries survive afterwards or commies would easily take over?

Comment: Why would aliens *only* attack NATO countries ?  They'd just attack the whole planet.

Comment: How would the aliens know enough about Earth to know which countries were NATO, but not enough to know the purpose of NASA's mission? How do they have enough power to locate and destroy all the power stations, but not enough to hide from, redirect, destroy, or otherwise interfere with the NASA mission?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of story which results in a generation dedicate to the perfection of warfare to take the fight to the alien's home planet a. la. Ender's Game.  It looks like we got lucky and found a group of aliens that literally has no concept of how to engage in violence!

Comment: @CortAmmon Not engaged in violence? What about any death toll in the direct destruction of the power stations and collateral deaths due to loss of medical & hospital services? Perhaps the aliens have allies in the Warsaw Pact countries. Hooray! The Southern Hemisphere is intact!

Comment: @a4android What I mean is, if the aliens had any concept of how to engage in violence, they would not be foolish enough to make such a tiny strike, and then walk away without observing the response.  It's like being angered by an anthill, so you rip the legs off one ant, and then walk away confident that the 'hill has learned its lesson.

Comment: @CortAmmon I like your anthill analogy. The aliens' precise attack on power stations in NATO nations suggests this is closer to killing the anthil's queen ant than a random worker or soldier ant. Our capacity to retaliate against the aliens may be no more than a single anthill's against human civilisation & technology. This scenario has a wide range of imponderables leaving us in a realm of speculation & guesswork.

Comment: Welcome to the site yamora.  Please check out the [help] and [tour] to get an idea of expectations on the site.  As it stands this question is far too broad.

Answer (score 2):

You need to detail a bit better.

No military installation relies on "normal" power stations. They have local and not-so-local backups to last for long time. In war-like-conditions power plants are a primary target, even forgetting about aliens.

If Aliens destroyed everything, including backups and backup-of-backups then the Western world would have *a lot* of problems even without "commies" help.

Assuming Eastern world is not touched by Alien retaliation they would be *very welcome* to invade Europe and thus save quite a bit of lives. Even in 70's *no western nation* would survive a prolonged and *generalized* loss of power.

OTOH destruction of "regular civilian power stations", leaving backups fully functional, might be survived and have small *immediate* impact on military capabilities; of course rebuilding all power installations would be a major setback exposing Western world to a *mid-term* vulnerability which may be exploited from East.

Main vulnerability would come from (forced) usage of military backups to power civilian apparatus, depleting military redundancy.

Comment: Good point about military forces having independent power and being able to survive massive civilian power losses. Less an invasion by the Warsaw Pact, more a 'humanitarian rescue mission'. My guess is NATO would go to whatever DEFCON was immediately prior to all out war to prevent a Soviet take-over. of course, Martial law would be declared to assist the civil power maintain order. Plus one.

Comment: Besides -- mobile power stations are all over the place, especially in North America (most diesel-electric locos can be configured for the job)

Comment: If you know a question is too broad you should comment and VTC rather than answering.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of both NATO and Warsaw Pact nuclear deterrence was to prevent the other from "taking over" pretty much no matter what else happened...*especially* in the absence of strong conventional forces. And it worked.

Aliens, terrorism, Godzilla, Spider Man, whatever - unless they could stop all three legs of the nuclear triad from obliterating one side, it wasn't going to make a *military* difference to the cold war.

That is why most Cold War drama in Europe was centered around espionage, subversion, and influence operations.